# I have an issue with the following Java code on eclipse (unreachable code)

Tags: java, eclipse

First of all, I would like to make this clear. The following is a homework assignment for university, therefore I cannot post the actual code due to university rules on plagiarism. But here is a modified code which should explain my problem

The code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Foo 
{
  //creating an object array
  private static Object[] objectArray;

  //main method
  public static void main(String []args)
  {
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Would you like to initialize array (y/n)?");
     if(kb.nextChar() == 'y')
       {
          initializeArray();
       }
     someMethod();
  }
public static void someMethod()
  {
    //checking if the array is empty, if the case, quit the method
    if(isEmpty());
    {
        System.out.println("Empty array");
        return;
    }
    //if the above check returns false (array is not empty) continues on 
    //with the code which is tagged by eclipse as unreachable
  }
public static boolean isEmpty()
  {
     for(Object a : objectArray)
      {
        if(a != null)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
   }
public static void initializeArray()
  {
     objectArray[0] = new Object();
  }
}
```

Now for my question: 
The code above gives me an error due to `unreachable code`. I checked over and over again and I know for a fact that the only way to get an `unreachable code` is if `isEmpty` always return `false`. This is not the case. Is it a possible bug in eclipse? If it is a mistake on my part, can you give me a detailed explanation on where I went wrong please.

Comment: Remove that extra semi-colon on the line with the `if`.

Comment: Oh god... I don't know how I missed that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is having some issues. Issues are

1. Change

   ```
    if(isEmpty());
   ```

   to

   ```
    if(new Foo().isEmpty())
   ```

   Since `isEmpty()` is non static method cannot be referenced from a static method and remove that extra semicolon.
2. class is not closed (means missing `}` at the end of the class).
3. Where did you find this `nextChar()` method?

   Check [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

   If you would like to take the first character from `Scanner.next` then

   Instead of

   ```
   kb.nextChar() == 'y'
   ```

   use

   ```
   kb.next().charAt(0) == 'y'
   ```

Comment: Why d/w. May I know the reason for this.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I didn't use the nextChar in the actual code, since I needed to compare a string, but I didn't want my code to be too similar to what I'm submitting so I changed it as much as possible while typing the question. I'll keep that in mind though if it comes up on an exam, so thanks for pointing that out.  Ends up, my problem was the semi colon after the if statement which I overlooked. the closing brackets and static isEmpty were present, I just forgot to type it down. Once again, Thanks for your help.